# Bieberbach’s 1934 lecture on “German mathematics”

Tags: mathematicians, 20th-century, nazi-germany, 1930s

Does anyone know of an English translation of [Ludwig Bieberbach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludwig_Bieberbach)’s infamous 1934 Berlin lecture, delivered at the annual conference of the *Deutscher Verein zur Förderung des mathematischen und naturwissenschaftlichen Unterrichts*? This is the lecture in which he tried to draw a distinction between German mathematics and Jewish/French mathematics, claiming them to be “separated by an unbridgeable chasm”.

Comment: Ludwig Bieberbach, "Persönlichkeitsstruktur und mathematisches Schaffen." *Unterrichtsblätter für Mathematik und Naturwissenschaften,* Vol. 40, No. 7, 1934, pp. 236-243. I haven't been able to find a publicly accessible scan yet, Google provides only tiny snippets.

Comment: Ludwig Bieberbach, "Persönlichkeitsstruktur und mathematisches Schaffen." *Forschungen und Fortschritte*, Vol. 10, No. 18, Jun. 1934, pp. 235-237. I am not entirely certain of all details of this citation which I had to piece together from multiple sources. Again, Google offers only useless snippets.

Comment: The press report appears to be: "Neue Mathematik. Ein Vortrag von Prof. Bieberbach", *Die Deutsche Zukunft*, Vol. 2, April 8, 1934. The Bavarian State Library appears to hold volumes 1 through 8 of this publication, but they have not been digitized. The actual talk this refers to seems to have occurred in Berlin on April 3, 1934.

Comment: Do you have a transcript of the lecture in the original German?

Comment: Based on an hour-long Google search, an English translation of "Persönlichkeitsstruktur und mathematisches Schaffen" does not seem to exist yet.

Comment: Bohr commented on Bieberbach's talk in a Danish newspaper, but I have not been able to locate a scan of the publication: Harald Bohr, "'Ny Matematik' i Tyskland." *Berlingske Aften*, May 1, 1934, p. 9.

Comment: I would settle for an online transcript of the talk (in German) that I could feed to Google translate to get a rough sense of what Bieberbach said. (At the moment I am especially interested in how he classified Dedekind.)

Comment: @JamesPropp "how he classified Dedekind"  that's an excellent question to pursue!